# How can I open the current instance of Excel from my application?

Tags: c#, excel

How can I open my Excel worksheet in the *current* open instance of Microsoft Excel? When I use my code, a new instance of Excel is opened.

```
 private Excel.Application xlApp;
 private Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
 private Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

 xlApp = new Excel.Application();
 xlApp.Visible = true;

 xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(textBox1.Text);
 xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
```

Comment: Just for future reference, the `new` keyword usually opened a new instance of the specific variable. Secondly, you can not open a **Running** excel worksheet. Microsoft prevents you from doing that. You have to open the excel file to edit  it, not fish it from memory.

Comment: @NewAmbition No, you *can* open a running excel worksheet.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2009/03/12/attaching-to-an-already-running-office-application-from-your-application-using-getactiveobject-or-bindtomoniker.aspx)

Comment: @azmodan, shows my knowledge :/ I apologise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like the following to get a reference to a running Excel instance (if there is one):

```
public Excel.Application TryGetExistingExcelApplication()
{
    try
    {
        object o = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        return (Excel.Application)o;
    }
    catch (COMException)
    {
        // Probably there is no existing Excel instance running, return null
        return null;
    }
}
```

Once you have a reference to a running instance, you can access it's Workbooks collection.

One caveat: if you try to automate an existing Excel instance, you may get "server busy" exceptions.  To avoid this, you can implement `IOleMessageFilter` error handlers. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772(vs.80).aspx) describes how to do it for automating Visual Studio; the technique is identical for automating Excel.

Comment: This doen't wok on IIS in published mode. Can you hint why its not